# How to solve "Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?."?

Tags: tikz-pgf, syntax, syntax-checker

The code that gives this error message is

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=.8]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,height=12cm,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,hide axis]
    %------------------------------------- Gráficos -------------------------------------
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^(x),e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^(x),e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^(x),-e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^(x),-e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^(x),2*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^(x),2*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^(x),-2*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^(x),-2*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^(x),3*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^(x),3*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^(x),-3*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^(x),-3*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^(x),4*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^(x),4*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^(x),-4*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^(x),-4*e^(-x));
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,White,domain=-8:10,samples=20] plot (x,0);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,White,domain=-8.5:10,samples=20] plot (0,x);
    % -------------------------------------- Setas --------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(8.5,0) (0,0)};
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-8.5,0) (0,0)};
            \node[scale=2] (x) at (9.3,0) {$\lambda_1$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.28 with {\arrow{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0,8.5)};
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0,-8.5)};
            \node[scale=2] (y) at (0,9.3) {$\lambda_2$};
        \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I did a test by removing parts of the code and putting them back on. The part in which the error message stopped showing up,when removed, was:

```
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^(x),e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^(x),e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^(x),-e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^(x),-e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^(x),2*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^(x),2*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^(x),-2*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^(x),-2*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^(x),3*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^(x),3*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^(x),-3*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^(x),-3*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^(x),4*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^(x),4*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^(x),-4*e^(-x));
\addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^(x),-4*e^(-x));
```

So I replaced all the semi-colons, but the error message persisted. Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW, ln(e^2)=2.  ln(e^2/3)=2-ln(3) while ln(e^(2/3))=2/3.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Yes, it is. I did it like that to make sure that the edge values on the graph are the same.  Because, e^(ln(e^2)) = e^2 and e^(ln(e^2/3)) = e^2/3, so 3*e^(ln(e^2/3)) = e^2.

Comment: Also, before posting it here, the domain on the first four \addplot was from -2 to 2, but written like I did makes the code much more readable, since all the plot commands line up.

Comment: You could just add spaces if you want them to line up.   But if you find the complicated version more readable, more power to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is cause by the round brackets:

The syntax is `\addplot[] ( e^x , e^-x);` and not `\addplot[] ( e^(x) , e^(-x))`

If you need the round brackets `()` you need to embed the expression in curly brackets `{}` like `\addplot[] ({e^(x)},{e^(-x)});`

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=.8]
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,height=12cm,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,hide axis]
    %------------------------------------- Gráficos -------------------------------------
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^x,e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^x,e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (e^x,-e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1),samples=1000] plot (-e^x,-e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^x,2*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^x,2*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (2*e^x,-2*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2),samples=1000] plot (-2*e^x,-2*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^x,3*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^x,3*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (3*e^x,-3*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3),samples=1000] plot (-3*e^x,-3*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^x,4*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^x,4*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (4*e^x,-4*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,thick,domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4),samples=1000] plot (-4*e^x,-4*e^-x);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,White,domain=-8:10,samples=20] plot (x,0);
        \addplot[,ytick=\empty,yticklabel=\empty,White,domain=-8.5:10,samples=20] plot (0,x);
    % -------------------------------------- Setas --------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(8.5,0) (0,0)};
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(-8.5,0) (0,0)};
            \node[scale=2] (x) at (9.3,0) {$\lambda_1$};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[thick,decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.28 with {\arrow{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0,8.5)};
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,0) (0,-8.5)};
            \node[scale=2] (y) at (0,9.3) {$\lambda_2$};
        \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! On some codes I used { }, so this error message did not occur. I would have never figured this one out alone. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 3):

Off-topic complement to nice @Roland answer. OP code can be much shorter and simpler:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{130}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=.8]
    \begin{axis}[
height=12cm,
axis lines=middle,
hide axis,
clip=false,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
%
samples=101,
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
                ]
    %------------------------------------- Gráficos -------------------------------------
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1)] plot (e^x,e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1)] plot (-e^x,e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1)] plot (e^x,-e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/1):ln(e^2/1)] plot (-e^x,-e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2)] plot (2*e^x,2*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2)] plot (-2*e^x,2*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2)] plot (2*e^x,-2*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/2):ln(e^2/2)] plot (-2*e^x,-2*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3)] plot (3*e^x,3*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3)] plot (-3*e^x,3*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3)] plot (3*e^x,-3*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/3):ln(e^2/3)] plot (-3*e^x,-3*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4)] plot (4*e^x,4*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4)] plot (-4*e^x,4*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4)] plot (4*e^x,-4*e^-x);
        \addplot[domain=-ln(e^2/4):ln(e^2/4)] plot (-4*e^x,-4*e^-x);
    % -------------------------------------- Setas --------------------------------------
        \begin{scope}[decoration={markings,mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow[very thick]{>}}}]
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (8.5,0) node[right, scale=2] {$\lambda_1$} -- (0,0);
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,8.5) node[above, scale=2] {$\lambda_2$} -- (0,0);
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (-8.5,0) -- (0,0);
            \draw[postaction={decorate}] (0,-8,5) -- (0,0); 
        \end{scope}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not great at this by any means, so I probably do everything in the most inefficient way possible. However, the arrows of the $\lambda_2$ axis need to be pointing away from the origin, thats why I did the two scopes with different values on the position of the decoration marking.

Comment: Is there a way of inverting the arrows on the vertical lines?

Comment: @FractalAdmirer. yes. On two ways: )i= inver direction of drawing lines, (ii) instead `\arrow` use `\arrowreversed` in code for `decoration`.